# Cardinal arithmetic confusion: What is $|\Bbb R|+|\Bbb N|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I do not understand how to calculate addition two cardinals.
I know that the formula as follows:

if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two cardinals, then

$\alpha + \beta= |\{(a,0):a\in \alpha\}\cup\{(b,1):b\in\beta\}|$.

If $\alpha=\mathbb{R}$ and $\beta=\mathbb{N}$, what's cardinals of $\alpha+\beta$?

Answer (score 1):

What is the cardinality of $\Bbb R\times\{0\}\cup\Bbb N\times\{1\}$? You can notice that this is a subset of $\Bbb R\times\{0,1\}$, whose cardinality is $|\Bbb R|+|\Bbb R|$.

This gives you an upper bound, and if you can calculate it, it will also give you a lower bound for the cardinality of $|\Bbb R|+|\Bbb N|$.

As a final remark, you might want to distinguish between a set and its cardinal.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try using Schroder-Bernstein to show that $|\mathbb{R}|+|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{R}|$.  To do this, let $X=\{(a,0):a\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(b,1):b\in\mathbb{N}\}$; you want to find injections $\mathbb{R}\to X$ and $X\to\mathbb{R}$.  The first one should be fairly easy; the second one will require some cleverness.

Comment: Can I deduce that $\alpha+\beta=\max\{\alpha,\beta\}$?

Comment: That is true in this particular case, but the argument does not generalize.  Using the axiom of choice, it is possible (but nontrivial!) to prove that $\alpha+\beta=\max(\alpha,\beta)$ as long as at least one of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is infinite.  Without the axiom of choice, addition of infinite cardinals can be quite difficult to understand (in particular, there exist infinite cardinals such that $\alpha+\beta\not=\max(\alpha,\beta)$ because "$\max(\alpha,\beta)$" does not even exist!).